# Genymotion @ Ubuntu 16.04 - AAPT tool not found at this location

Tags: genymotion, android-sdk-tools

After moving Android SDK folder to another location, Genymotion (v 2.9.0) shows warning "AAPT tool not found at this location" under Settings -> ADB and show empty location in pop-up dialog while Android device startup.

What and how I need to fix?

Thank you